# regular expression to match tag with or without close tag?

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling with detect these patterns in a content body:

```
   [tagname blah blah blah]blah blah blah[/tagname]  // pattern 1: with close tag

   [tagname blah blah blah]   //pattern 2: without close tag
```

Pattern examples:

`[vimeo align='center' id='123']//player.vimeo.com/video/123[/vimeo]`

`[vimeo align='left' id='123']`

Right now I came up with this regular expression capturing both:

```
/\[(?<name>vimeo)[^\]]+\](?:(.*?)\[\/\g<name>\])?/
```

Notice there is a `?` at the end of `(?:(.*?)\[\/\g<name>\])` to make the subpattern optional. But there is a problem with this. It will falsely match `[vimeo align='center' id='123']//player.vimeo.com/video/123[/youtube]` (notice the closing tag is `youtube` not `vimeo` now)

Can anyone help me to fix this regular expression? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. all content in a long string

Comment: as in the description, `[vimeo align='center' id='123']//player.vimeo.com/video/123[/youtube]` will falsely captured by the regular expression.

Comment: @anubhava I mean `\[(?<name>vimeo)[^\]]+\](?:(.*?)\[\/\g<name>\])?` should not capture anything in `[vimeo align='center' id='123']//player.vimeo.com/video/123[/youtube]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\[(?<name>vimeo)[^\]]+\](?:(.*?)\[\/\g<name>\]|(?![^[]*\[\/))
```

instead of making the end tag optional, I'll look foward to check if there isn't anty closing tag

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uvUXzy/1)